# How to make loacalhost django interact with posgtres worked in docker container?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I'm run my project through  docker. It contains few  django's apps (backend), vue.js (frontend),  celery, redis and postgres. All services working as expected, but now I need edit my project source code.
For  it I want to stop container that responsible for backend and frontend and to run them on localhost. And other services like redis, postgress and etc I leave to work in containers. How can I do this better way?

I was doing:
stop mentioned containers,
leave working in containers other services,
gave python manage.py runserver.

But now I get this error.:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
                Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
                TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I guess my project can't access to postgres db worked container. Why is it like this?
I convinced in terminal that my db is running in docker container on port 5432 .

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is your localhost IP but docker uses a separate network by design. You should run `docker inspect <postgres_container_id> | grep "IPAddress"` to get the address assigned by docker.

Comment: When you launch the database container, do you have a `docker run -p ????:5432`, or a Compose `ports: [????:5432]` setting?  Connect to `127.0.0.1` (except on Docker Toolbox) and that port number.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, you thought right direction. The solution was to specify the external port in my file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my docker compose file I changed instruction "expose - 5432" to "ports - 5432:5432".
And after this projec is running on the localhost as expected.